# Is there a list of all available color options for `col` in R plot?

Tags: r, plot, colors, visualization

I have an R function in a package that calls `plot`, and I want my function to test that what users set as their `col` value (which is passed to `plot`) is a valid argument.
For example, if they specify `col='red'` or `col='#b4a7d6'`, I want the test to pass, but if they specify `col='bbb'`, I want the test to fail.

If I had such a list, I would set up a test like this:

```
list_of_legit_colors <- c('red', '#b4a7d6')
if(!col %in% list_of_legit_colors){
  stop("Color must exist for R plotting")
}
```

I'm wondering where I can find that full list of color options (`list_of_legit_colors`) that work for R plots.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289009/check-if-character-string-is-a-valid-color-representation#13290832

Comment: `plot(1, col = 'bbb')` _does_ fail. if you want it to fail earlier, i guess you could just run `col2rgb('bbb')` at some point. this seems like an xy problem by the way

Comment: colors() is probably what you're looking for

Comment: This works `tryCatch({col2rgb(col)}, error=function(e) {
    print('col value entered is not a valid value')})`. Note that this answer is not in the link above.